# how can i install sun-java6-sdk on ubuntu 11 oneiric

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

I added all the required package sources to my list file and nomatter what i do i keep getting this:

> E: Package 'sun-java6-jdk' has no installation candidate

Anyone knows which way i can install sun-java6-jdk on ubuntu 11? (I have successfully installed on ubuntu 10 but no way on 11).

for example i saw this tutorial:
http://leonardo-pinho.blogspot.com/2010/11/java-15-no-ubuntu-1010.html

however it did not help, anyone knows what to do?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean sun-java6-jdk - Sun Java(TM) Development Kit (JDK) 6?

You have to do it through a PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-plugin
```

Comment: Thank you so much! been trying for days to to get this to work...